# CREATE TYPE TypeName AS varchar(256)[]; This method of creating an Array in PostgreSQL is not working

Tags: postgresql

I can not create a Type of `VArray` in PostgreSQL.

I have this code in Oracle for the creation of the type:

```sql
TYPE FIELDS IS VARRAY(14) OF VARCHAR2(256);
```

and this is the code that I put in PostgreSQL PgAdmin:

```sql
CREATE TYPE FIELDS AS varchar(256)[];
```

Is there any other ways to create this type?

Comment: Without more context this is impossible to answer. But indeed a regular array is the closest to Oracle's `varray` in PL/SQL.

Comment: I'm truying to create a Type in postgresql like the one in Oracle(the code for oracle is correct but the one for postgresql isn't)

Comment: Why do you think you need to create a new type in order to use an array? Just declare a PL/pgSQL variable that's an array. Again: without more context this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot declare a new type as an array, but you can create a domain over this type and use that like a data type:

```
CREATE DOMAIN fields AS varchar(256)[];
```

It is often not a good idea to use arrays as column data type.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically you don't need to do anything to use a type as an array.
Every type in postgres has its corresponding array type (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html#SQL-CREATETYPE-ARRAY).

So, to use a `varchar(256)` array in a table, you could:

```
create table test1 (fields varchar(256)[]);
```

If you need to add more constraints to a type, you can look at [`create domain`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/sql-createdomain.html) as well.

As an aside, I've read many times that `text` is a better type than `varchar(N)` (if it's just about disk space optimization).
If you want to guarantee a max text length, you could always use a `check (length(value) < 255)` on your column definition.

Comment: It is fine to use `varchar(n)` if you want to impose a length limit.